# Building x64 C++ project from command line says: This operation should only take place on the UI thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build, 64-bit, devenv

Visual Studio 2013 has a problem when building, it displays an error message as follows:

```
c:>devenv /build debug /project (project name) /projectconfig "debug|x64" (solution Name).sln
```

> 1>This operation should only take place on the UI thread.

Answer (score 20):

I just ran into this with Visual Studio 2015 compiling C++ code (error: This operation should only take place on the UI thread).  Finally traced it to the .vcxproj.filters file for the project that was failing to compile.  This file had been merged from another code stream and was missing a closing "ClCompile" XML tag in one spot.  Apparently this leads to the error, although compiling in the IDE worked fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! That did a great help.

Comment: Thanks! you save me from a long debugging night

Comment: I had the same issue and it appeared that after a new merge I accidentaly have broken vcxproj.filters file. When I fixed it - this issue has gone away

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround : use

msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64 (solution Name).sln..

moreover I have no issues using devenv /build once I have used msbuild.

Black magic !